# AWS Connect: Custom CCP bring to front

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I'm aware that the Amazon Connect CCP is based on the idea that it can be developed and integrated in any website at will without the restrictions of a closed product. However the fact that it is embedded, means it has some agent usability drawbacks. While browsing to multiple tabs you can eventually loose the tab where CCP resides. This means that if the agents needs to mute, hold, ... it might take a while before they find the right tab.

Is it possible to create a CCP that it can be always visible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I set up an external screen pop as detailed in the AWS blog, and I have the issue on Windows 10 and Chrome. When call coming the pop-up notification apears, when clicking on the pop-up notification, you are not redirected to the CCP browser window.

However, I also tried the same setup on Firefox and the issue disappears: when clicking on the pop-up notification, the CCP browser tab gains focus correctly. Additionally, I set up another screen pop with a different instance and S3 bucket, using the files provided in the blog, and it yielded the same result: the issue appears with Chrome, but not with Firefox. It all points in the direction of it being an issue related to the integration between Chrome and the Windows pop-up notifications (the same problem for MacOS).

Comment: What I have thought is a simple chrome extension